# Logging stderr and stdout to console

Tags: java, logging

I want to move stderr and stdout to the console and move them to some file .

Suppose In my java class I write siome logger statements .. Info,WARN .. 
and some exception( throw new Runtime Exception ) is coming which is going to the stderr

and I invoke that java class from script and move it to some file .

I want that file contains both logger and exception .

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

public class HelloExample2{

```
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloExample2.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            HelloExample2 obj = new HelloExample2();
            try{
                    obj.divide();
            }catch(ArithmeticException ex){
                    System.out.println("yeah buddy .. puchi");
                    logger.error("Sorry, something wrong!");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    private void divide(){

            int i = 10 /0;

    }
```

}

I want both ERROR log and exception get printed to some file

I am running my program like :-- 
./script_invoke_java > somefile.log

this file contains both loggers and exception ( I am taking about exceptions system.out are coming in file ).
I want to do this using log4J any suggestions ??

Comment: left it Snickers you don't understand the question take

Comment: You don't understand SO.

Answer (score 4):

You want your call to look like this:

```
logger.error("Sorry,...", ex);
```

[Take a look at the javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#error(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Throwable))

If you don't want to edit the java file itself, you can use shell redirection:

```
./script_invoke_java &> output.log
```

Comment: you are telling is one way of doing this but this is not feasible in my case as I have to change in lots of classes and have to add try and catch ..

Comment: updated answer with alternate approach

Comment: yes Thanks it is working.  we can do something in log4j.properties  otherwise I have to change lots of script files as I am referrring to same log4j in my project ??


Something like below :-- it is not working right now

 log4j.rootLogger=, stdout, stderr
# configure stdout
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5

Comment: If the answer worked for the original question, can you kindly click to accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [org.apache.logging.log4j.io.LoggerPrintWriter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-iostreams/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/io/LoggerPrintWriter.html) is something for you. You can create a instance of it and set it as `System.out` and `System.err`. This class will forward everything to a log4j logger with specific parameters and you can use log4j to put what every you like in a file.

Comment: can I do something in my log4J.properties

Comment: adding new class to me means I have to do the same for many classes and many projects

Comment: you have to do this once per Running Application. Not for every class.